# How am I getting this error if I'm not using the .equals method?

Tags: java, android, nullreferenceexception

```
String signInMethod;
...

...
if (signInMethod != null) {
    if (signInMethod.equals("google")) {
        intent.putExtra("signInMethod", "google");
    } else if (signInMethod.equals("email")) {
        intent.putExtra("signInMethod", "email");
    }
} else {
    intent.putExtra("signInMethod", "alreadySignedIn");
}
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

How am I getting this error if I'm not using the .equals method?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please post all of your code

Comment: These are the only references to signInMethod

Comment: also show which line throws the exception. Just a note, it's always better to write your equals like: if ( "google".equals(signInMethod) )

Comment: @Dylan you should understand that the error message you show doesn't state that's the variable causing the NPE

Comment: @Stultuske why is it better to do `if( "google".equals(signInMethod) )`?

Comment: @a_local_nobody because it makes it impossible for the statement to throw an NPE if you call the method on the String literal, whether you add a null-check or not.

Comment: @a_local_nobody it's quite simple, actually, a reference variable can be any valid instance (or null, when it's an Object), but "google" == null can never be true.

Comment: @Dylan that line can't throw that exception.

Comment: @user85421 which harder to find error would it hide, and why would it be harder to find?

Comment: @Stultuske ikr so is it something wrong with the IDE?

Comment: @Dylan I have no idea. Maybe there's a difference between the version you have compiled and the code you see, but that line doesn't call any method, it can't cause it.

Comment: @Dylan please post your complete error log in your question as well

Comment: @user85421 considering the fact there is a null-check done before, this would change nothing compared to the current code.

Comment: @user85421 same as with what I wrote. it wouldn't take more than a simple debug to figure out why it would be failing.

Comment: I tried cleaning and rebuilding but the error and the line in question, still don't match

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
  String signInMethod = null;
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(signInMethod)){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Some thing wrong please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        if (signInMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("google")) {
            intent.putExtra("signInMethod", "google");
        } else if (signInMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("email")) {
            intent.putExtra("signInMethod", "email");
        } else {
            intent.putExtra("signInMethod", "alreadySignedIn");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with local variable's default value. Make sure that you initialize your `signInMethod` with at least a `null`.

```
public void myMethod() {
    String signInMethod = null; // <--- THE FIX
    ...

    ...
    if (signInMethod != null) {
        if (signInMethod.equals("google")) {
            intent.putExtra("signInMethod", "google"); 
        } else if (signInMethod.equals("email")) {
            intent.putExtra("signInMethod", "email");
        }
    } else {
        intent.putExtra("signInMethod", "alreadySignedIn");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Compiler does not assign any value(even null) to a **local variable**. you have to initialize it as "Null" to make it work otherwise the **IF** statement does not work